# What is the "td:uuid" in IBM Connections API?

Tags: ibm-connections

Trying to download a file from my account on the Connections API. [The doc](https://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/lcwiki.nsf/xpAPIViewer.xsp?lookupName=IBM%20Connections%205.0%20API%20Documentation#action=openDocument&res_title=Retrieving_a_file_folder_ic50&content=apicontent) says:

The URI is: `/files/basic/api/collection/{collection-id}/entry`

With this note:

> {collection-id} is the value of the `<td:uuid>` element in the
>   collection's Atom entry document.

Where can I get this `td:uuid`?

Comment: td:uuid is the thread uuid, it's from this feed - https://<SERVER>/files/basic/api/collections/feed look for    <entry>
    <id>urn:lsid:ibm.com:td:ce6a3f00-5d3a-11df-b3a5-b6800a050301</id>
    <td:uuid>ce6a3f00-5d3a-11df-b3a5-b6800a050301</td:uuid>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try to access a file in a community, then use the following URI to receive an XML document that contains the td:uuid tag.

```
/files/basic/api/communitycollection/{community-id}/feed
```

If you try to access My Files, then the following URI should return the information

```
/files/basic/api/myuserlibrary/feed
```